# a simple algorithm to calculate a price but there is a problem

Tags: javascript

This is a js code very simple

```
let priceTl = document.getElementById("tl");
let priceSar = document.getElementById("sar");
let finalPrice = document.getElementById("price");

let convertFromTl = () => {
    let tl = priceTl.value;

  //toFixed(2) limits the decimals to 2 digits.
    priceSar.value = tl / 7.6503;

      if (priceSar.value * 0.1 <= 5) {
        finalPrice.value = priceSar.value + 5;
      }
      if (priceSar.value * 0.1 >= 15) {
        finalPrice.value = priceSar.value + 15;
      } else {
        finalPrice.value = priceSar.value * 1.1;
      }
};

priceTl.addEventListener("input", convertFromTl);
window.addEventListener("load", convertFromTl);
```

The code gets 3 data from the index.html - gets the `priceTl`, `priceSar`, `finalPrice`.
This is how my website looks like
[image]

It's a very simple calculator to put a price in the first input in Turkish lira which calculate it to Saudi Arabian riyals in the second input and so far there is no problem.

But the third input should check the second input the Saudi Arabian riyals if the (price * 0.1) is less than or equal to 5 then the final price should be the price in Saudi riyals + 5, and if the price *0.1 is bigger than or equal to 15 then the final price should equal 15.
and if it's between 5 and 15 then the final price should equal the Saudi riyals *1.1, and it should automatically update the data in the website but what happens for no reason is it calculates the final price as Saudi riyals *1.1 always even if the value is less than 5 or bigger than 15.

Comment: The value property returns a string

Comment: You need to chain *all* conditions with `else`, not just the last two.

Comment: @DanielA.White excellent point, especially in regards to `priceSar.value + 15`. Ahmed, why store the intermediate value in `priceSar.value`? A simple numeric variable would be much better and won't be converted to a string along the way

Answer (score 3):

```
  if (priceSar.value * 0.1 <= 5) {
    finalPrice.value = priceSar.value + 5;
  }

  if (priceSar.value * 0.1 >= 15) {
    finalPrice.value = priceSar.value + 15;
  } else {
    finalPrice.value = priceSar.value * 1.1;
  }
```

1. you are missing an `ELSE` in front of the second `if`. Thus, no matter if it's `<=5` that result will always be overrwriten by one of the final 2 calculations.
2. Why the second (`>=15`) never applies - you have to find out. Reverse engineered, it would apply only for prices larger than (`15 * 10 * 7.6503`) = 1.147,50 - is that expected?

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet will work according to your rules:

```js
let priceTl = document.getElementById("tl");
let priceSar = document.getElementById("sar");
let finalPrice = document.getElementById("price");

let convertFromTl = () => {
 const sar = priceTl.value / 7.6503;
 finalPrice.value = (sar<=50 ? sar+5 : sar>=150 ? sar+15 : sar*1.1).toFixed(2);   
 priceSar.value = sar.toFixed(2);
};

priceTl.addEventListener("input", convertFromTl);
convertFromTl();
```

```html
<input id="tl" type="text" value="1234"><br>
<input id="sar" type="text" value=""><br>
<input id="price" type="text" value="">
```

Following Phil's comment I now store the sar price in the (numeric) variable `sar`.

The `if` / `else` blocks were replaced by a one liner using the ternary operators `?` and `:`.

Comment: _"Note the unary + operator"_... I'd just keep the numeric value in a separate variable, eg `const tl = priceTL.value / 7.6503`

Comment: Yes, also possible - changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Don't really see a need for separate `tl` and `sar` variables but yeah, that's much better

Comment: Ok, I also eliminated the `tl` variable and rounded the currency values to 2 digits after the decimal point.